# Object.create not working in function

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
function Mammal(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.offspring = [];
}

Mammal.prototype.sayHello = function(){
    return "My name is " + this.name + ", I'm a " + this.constructor.name;
}



function Cat(name, color){
    Mammal.call(this, name);
    this.color = color;
}
```

Now, when I call Object.create from with this function:

```
function extendWithObjectCreate(child, parent) {
    child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);    
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
}
```

Object.create does not return an object linked to the parent prototype.

Can you use Object.create within a function?

Comment: Could you explain how you're calling `extendWithObjectCreate`?

Comment: How do you pass `child` and `parent` to `extendWithObjectCreate`?

Comment: extendWithObjectCreate(Child, Mammal)

Comment: Why do you think that "*Object.create does not return an object linked to the parent prototype.*"? What did you observe? What link did you expect that you didn't find?

Answer (score 0):

When I do this, it comes out just fine:

```js
function Mammal(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.offspring = [];
}

Mammal.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    return "My name is " + this.name + ", I'm a " + this.constructor.name;
}

function Cat(name, color) {
    Mammal.call(this, name);
    this.color = color;
}

function extendWithObjectCreate(child, parent) {
    child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);    
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
}

extendWithObjectCreate(Cat, Mammal);

alert(new Cat('Muffin','blue').sayHello());
```

The prototype is working. However, because `Object.create()` creates an object with a *prototype*, the prototypical properties are not set on the object itself. So, while `Cat.prototype.sayHello` exists, `Cat.prototype.hasOwnProperty('sayHello')` is false.

Comment: @Qantas Chrome also has `Object.hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken, Firefox doesn't have that. That doesn't do what you think it does, as it will call it on `Object`, not `Cat.prototype`.